# Upload URL & source URL for blogging from Microsoft Word (with Blogspot default image host)

Tags: microsoft-word, blogging

I want to do blogging with BlogSpot and Microsoft Word and found this, but http://blogspot.com or http://mysite.blogspot.com doesn't allowed. anyone know which url should I enter here for using blogspot default image provider?
or atleast IMGUR host?
many thanks!!

[image]